# Angular - route with multiple resolvers

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to implement a route with multiple resolvers. I am using this example:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-resolves-multiple-resolves?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts
```

This example shows how to implement two resolvers for the same route:

```
{ 
  path: 'news',
  component: NewsComponent,
  resolve: {
    news: NewsResolver, // first resolve
    alternativeNews: AlternativeNewsResolver // second resolve
  }
}
```

What I need is to be able to send different data to each resolver. Here is how it's been implemented in my system:

```
path: '',
component: aComponent,
resolve: { model: aResolver },
data: { resolvedata: 'data' },
```

Here is aResolver, simplified:

```
export class aResolver {
  constructor() {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
      const moduleName = route.data.resolvedata;
   ....
  }
}
```

I am trying something like this to get started with just one resolver:

```
resolve: {  
  data: {
    resolvedata: 'data'
  }, 
   model: aResolver
},
```

That does not work.

Please share your ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the latest version of angular, you could create a factory function which returns a resolver function (see https://angular.io/api/router/ResolveFn).

You could pass the configuration data to this factory function as an argument in order to configure the resolver:

```
resolve: {
    model: aResolverFactory('data')
},

const aResolverFactory =
  (data: string): (() => Observable<any>) =>
  () => {
    // Resolver code here
    console.log(data);
    return of(true);
  };
```

Comment: Do you mind giving a bit more detail/code example how exactly that might work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a "smarter" singleton `NewsService`?

```js
@Inject({
  providedIn: 'root' // This is important
  …
})
export class NewsService {
  private toggle = false

  private getRegularNews(): Observable<News[]> { … }
  private getAlternateNews(): Observable<News[]> { … }
  public getNews(): Observable<News[]> {
    const news$ = this.toggle ? this.getRegularNews() : this.getAlternateNews()
    this.toggle = !this.toggle
    return news$
  }
}
```

And then from your component:

```js
@Component({…})
export class YourNewsComponent {
  news$ = this.newsService.getNews()
  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) {}
}
```

Comment: Not sure how is that related to the router.

Comment: Apologies if the answer wasn't good enough: I am just offering something a tad simpler that just works